# How to I send an HTML string back to the browser?

Tags: c#, html

How do I return an HTML document to a browser and have it display using C#?  Do I have to save it on the server and do a response.redirect or what?

Comment: You haven't described your scenario at all. What sort of server are you writing?

Comment: By the answers to cryptic questions I have seen lately in SO, I think *guessing* is a skill I have to develop more...

Comment: http://blog.brianlawler.org/2009/05/helloworld.html

Answer (score 3):

Saving it on the server isn't necessary.  Keep in mind that HTTP doesn't transfer "files."  It transfers responses to requests, and those responses consist of headers and content.  All you need to do is send that HTML string as the content.

For the most part, if you're doing ASP.NET WebForms, your headers are probably set up correctly for you.  You can manually modify them in the `Response.Headers` if you need to.  But if this is happening in, for example, a `Page_Load` then you likely won't need to.

What you *will* need to do is decide how you want that content delivered.  Do you want it to be part of the current page?  If so, set that string to the content of a control on the page.  A `Literal` will do nicely.  If the page has no content, then just `Response.Write` the content and be done with it.  (You can call `Response.End` as well if need be.)

Or is this not happening inside the scope of a page?  Or are you using the MVC framework?  Or do you have some other setup?  More information will help us to help you.  But the main point remains that it's all about headers and content.  Your HTML string is the content and just needs to be written to the response.

Answer (score 0):

No, just output a suitable HTTP response header then the document as the body of the HTTP response.